Why can't Xcode recognize my header file even though it is in the same folder as my cpp file?
My Xcode is able to recognize the PrecondViolatedExcep.h file in my ArrayQueue.h file:
#ifndef ARRAY_QUEUE_H
#define ARRAY_QUEUE_H

#include "QueueInterface.h"
#include "PrecondViolatedExcep.h"

template<class ItemType>
class ArrayQueue : public QueueInterface<ItemType>
{
private:
    // Constants and data members
    static const int DEFAULT_CAPACITY = 1;
    ItemType* queueArray;
    int frontIndex;
    int backIndex;
    int capacity;
    int itemCount;

public:
    // Constructors and destructor
    ArrayQueue();
    ArrayQueue(const ArrayQueue& another);
    ~ArrayQueue();
    
    // Queue operations
    bool isEmpty() const override;
    bool enqueue(const ItemType& newEntry) override;
    bool dequeue() override;
    ItemType peekFront() const override;

private:
    // Helper function for resizing the array
    void resize(int newCapacity);
};

#include "ArrayQueue.cpp"
#endif

But, it is not able to recognize it in my PrecondViolatedExcep.cpp file:
#include "PrecondViolatedExcep.h"

PrecondViolatedExcep::PrecondViolatedExcep(const std::string& message) : std::logic_error(message.c_str())
{
}

And my QueueInterface.h file:
#ifndef QUEUE_INTERFACE_H
#define QUEUE_INTERFACE_H


template<class ItemType>
class QueueInterface
{
public:
    // Checks if the queue is empty
    virtual bool isEmpty() const = 0;
    
    // Adds a new item to the back of the queue
    virtual bool enqueue(const ItemType& newEntry) = 0;
    
    // Removes the item at the front of the queue
    virtual bool dequeue() = 0;
    
    // Retrieves the item at the front of the queue
    virtual ItemType peekFront() const = 0;
    
    // Virtual destructor
    virtual ~QueueInterface() {}
};
#include "PrecondViolatedExcep.h"
#endif

I have two extra files called ArrayQueue.cpp and PrecondViolatedExcep.h itself. These five files are in the same folder and directory.
Does anyone know what is wrong with this, or how I can fix it?
I tried commenting the #include "PrecondViolatedExcep.h" statement in my QueueInterface.h file, but it only lead to more errors. I have also tried creating a new project, folder, and new files with the same name and code, but it gave 2 errors as I tried to run it:
Undefined Symbols:
Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Although, I cannot find this error anywhere in my code, and I do not know how to fix it.
Can anyone help me with this?

What does your "does not recognize" even mean? Does it not find the file?

Does this answer your question? Why can templates only be implemented in the header file? ArrayQueue and QueueInterface need to have their implementations in their header files.

To get details on a linker error, you need to expand the link operation in the report navigator.
